# CSS file wont update

Tags: css

I am currently working on a website, but my stylesheet wont update. I have made sure that my files have been uploaded correctly, and I have cleared my cache etc. I even visited the directory of the CSS file and clicked refresh like 50 times. The only way it works is if I rename my CSS file and change the name where I link it. Please help!

Comment: you should check your web server. Maybe you are caching static files

Comment: Thank you but 1: I don't know what that means, 2: Adding a query string works, but thank you sir! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a timestamp/version to your css.

Example

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/yourcss.css?1" />
```

or

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/yourss.css?<?php echo time(); ?>" />
```

Edit:

You could also use `filemtime()` PHP function, this returns the last edited time.

A small function example:

```
    <?php
        function editTime($folder, $file) {
            return filemtime($folder . '/'.$file);
        }
    ?>
```

Then you would to this in HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/yourcss.css?<?php echo editTime('css', 'yourcss.css'); ?>" />
```

Comment: I have been struggling with this for weeks, thank you!! I love you man

Comment: Note that this will forcibly download the styles, even if nothing has changed.

Comment: @jhpratt with the first example it will. But I doubt it will with the 2nd edit. Since the timestamp will remain the same, which should be cached in browser. Unless the file was edited and timestamp changes.

Comment: This method will increase the cache size. So, should not be used.

Answer (score 0):

That sometimes happenes...
To solve this problem you need to compile your web, then hold the Control button on your keyboard and press F5 few times.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try hard refreshing the page by pressing

`Cntl+F5`

2. Or you can use any live updater (By default comes in Bracket). This allow you to update the page in real time.
3. And thirdly, If you are using Chrome/Mozilla then go to its developter tools and find the option to hard reload and check it. Then on you page do right-click and click inspect element. This will allow you to always refresh the page hard if your developer tool is active.
4. can be solved by proper deleting of browser cache.

Comment: I spammed the CTRL+F5 literally (not joking) like 200 times from anger, but thanx!

Comment: May be something else was preventimg it from this thing. I am doing web development from two years. Faced this issue many times in starting. But one of these method work for me. Try using 2nd option, it should work.

Comment: You should not accept any answer that is working. First check its pros and cons.